# Wildstar cancel subscription

Tags: wildstar

Since I bought Wildstar and a 3 month subscription, I have barely played the game because of serious lack of time. Therefore, I am forced to cancel my subscription.
However, when I click "MANAGE SUBSCRIPTION", I only have the options to choose a payment method, and not to cancel my payment.
Standard, monthly fee, by Visa is selected.

One important thing to notice is that I might have canceled it already last month, but I might have forgotten about it. This could explain why I can't cancel it.

Anyone an idea?

Comment: Check your email for a cancellation confirmation?

Comment: Negative :(. And I assume that they would send me mails to reinvite me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to unsubcribe, you're looking at the wrong place. When you click on "Manage subscription", it allows you to change it.

To unsubscribe, go to the "TRANSACTION HISTORY" tab (on the right, just under "ACCOUNT MANAGEMENT" when you are on your profile), then on the "Subscription" tab (see the screenshot I made).

There, you can cancel your subscription. Not the most obvious, but there is also a link on the page where you manage your subscription too (but it's small and at the bottom of the page)

[image]

Comment: So, did it work fine for you?

Comment: Yes, I just checked it and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot and obviously, thumbs up! :)